# Is a binding target required to be a DP or is it enough to implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: wpf, binding

My question is in the title. I read that a binding target must be a DP but a reply I got from a moderator on the WPF forum seemed to indicate that it was sufficient for my class to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order to designate it as a binding target.

Answer (score 3):

Targets of data bindings are required to be dependency properties. WPF data binding sources do not have to be dependency properties. Obviously there must exist some kind of mechanism for the source object to notify the outside world when the bound property has changed. For that you have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and has an event named PropertyChanged, which identifies the particular event that's changed with a string.

for more please have a look at this links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522664.aspx

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/03/210946.html